# Is it possible to monetize Google Chrome ARC apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

Google released an [App Runtime for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) (Beta), called ARC, that lets you run your favorite Android apps on Chrome OS.
*Is it possible to monetize Google Chrome ARC apps through Google Play or Chrome Web Store?*
(I would like to add an "unlock all features" in-app purchase option to my app)

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to have a free version and a paid version(using gradle). That way you can don't have to right custom payment support for each app, since I do not think that ARC supports Google plays in app payment interface.

Comment: Is there any special code that one needs to put in the Android app if submitting it as a paid Chrome app?  This wasn't clear to me from the documentation.

Comment: I see a lot of problems with this solution-- for one thing, I would hope that people who buy an app or in-app-items in the Play store would have their purchases reflected in the Web Store as well-- or at least the developer should have the option of double-charging for the same app/items.  Second, what about apps that use subscriptions rather than all-or-nothing item purchases?  I'm hoping that the in-app-item support makes it to these apps and it knows who you are based on whether you're logged in or not...

Answer (score 0):

You can create in-app products in Chrome Dev Dashboard with same IDs as in Google Play Dev Console. Users will be be directed to Chrome Web Store payment, no changes in code required. 
Unfortunately, there is no sync provided between services, so you'll have to manage synchronization of purchases yourself.

[Much more info here.](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/arc_in_app_payments)