# Chrome ARC, Android -- ways to make paid apps?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I've recently posted my Android app to Chrome Web Store using ARC Welder, and wondering about how I can make it a paid app.

Currently, for Android, I have a free version and an "unlocker" as a separate app on Google Play. The user installs the free version first, and then if he/she decides to "go pro", he/she purchases and installs the "unlocker" which talks to the free versions and activates it into "pro" mode.

So my questions:

- When packaging an Android app with ARC, it runs on its own, so there is no way to have a second app ("unlocker") running in the same Android "sandbox", correct?
- Is it possible for an Android / ARC app to access "purchased" state via Google Play APIs, say for checking if the user purchased the "unlocker" app on Android?

I assume that the answer is "no", at least for now:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

> Since ARC is in Beta, it doesn't support all of Google Play Services yet.
>   However, here are some available APIs:
>   Auth (OAuth2)
>   GCM
>   Google+ sign-in
>   Maps
>   Location
>   Ads

I don't see licensing APIs here.

- I found these links on monetizing Chrome apps:

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

Even if this also applies to Chrome OS (not sure), it seems to require JavaScript coding to talk Chrome Webstore APIs. Is it possible to access those from inside the Android ARC sandbox?

- Are there better options that I'm missing?

None? Should I just wait until Android ARC is fleshed out more and hope that it includes support for paid apps?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467571/is-it-possible-to-monetize-google-chrome-arc-apps

Answer (score 0):

The direct answers are:

1) You can bundle up two APKs so they both run in the same sandbox. But only one of them is launched as "your app". It is free to then launch or otherwise use the second APK as it sees fit.
2) But as you noticed, there is no way to easily check for a purchase/license right now.

Your best bet may be to wait for the Google Play Services license APIs to be implemented.